# Nginx redirect of picture URL from subdomain to CloudFront

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need a quick help with Nginx rewrites for old links.

Old link: `http://widgets.example.com/person/106400.jpg`

New link: `http://example.cloudfront.net/old/widgets/106400.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need a redirect not a rewrite, because the domain changes compltely, here's a simple redirect rule for all `jpg` files, if there's a better matching tell me and ill change my answer.

```
server {
  server_name widgets.example.com;
  location ~ \.jpg$ {
    return 301 http://example.cloudfront.net/old$request_uri;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** An edit for removing `/person`

```
server {
  server_name widgets.example.com;
  location ^~ /person/(.*\.jpg) {
    return 301 http://example.cloudfront.net/old/widgets$1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. Seems like it should work great. However I made a mistake in the 'new link'. See the fixed links in the original post. Appending just $request_uri will not work.

Comment: I'm just finishing an all day migration of a big site so I will look into this issue tomorrow. Should just be a quick regexp added to your solution.

Comment: is there any rules for the first folder? the `/person` or is it random ?

Comment: It's static.. always /person.

Answer (score 0):

There are two other ways in NGINX that I know of that achieve this:

If you know exactly what you want to replace you can use [ngx_http_sub_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html)

If you want to use regex or pattern matching in your replacements you can use a community module called [Substiutions](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/substitutions/)